# Anyway to use OR in expects for Protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

It is possible to do a `x.toEqual('hello').or.toEqual('bye')`?

I want to be able to do `Expects` that have multiple correct possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do an `if` statement that returns a boolean and then check if that boolean is true.

```
var test = false;
if(x=='hello' || x=='bye'){
    test = true;
}

expect(test).toEqual(true);
```

Comment: How about just `expect(x=='hello' || x=='bye').toEqual(true);`

Comment: Yea I didn't think of that, I just tried it and that works too

Comment: @MikeChristensen
Right now I tried 
    `expect(x=='hello' || x=='bye').toEqual(true)`
and it doesn't work... but if I do a regular one
    `expect(x=='hello').toEqual('hello');`
It's working without a hitch.. The error i'm getting is expects false t equal true.

Comment: Try `toBe` instead of `toEqual`. That's what I tried and it worked for me

Comment: For some reason the expect with is always coming out as false even though one of them is true.

Comment: If it's still not working can you post the code? I've tried this myself and I know it's possible.