# Using 'or' in Protractor expected conditions

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to write an expects statement in Protractor that uses the [or expected condition](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.or). However, the documentation does not have any examples of how to use 'or' or 'and' with these blocks.

I have tried doing

```
expect(myString).or.toEqual('a string').toEqual('another string')

expect(myString).toEqual('a string').or.toEqual('another string')
```

and just for kicks

```
expect(myString).toEqual('a string', 'another string')
```

This question has been asked [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434826/anyway-to-use-or-in-expects-for-protractor) but only a workaround was given.

I would like to actually use the or function that is built into Protractor as it should allow the message to read something like

```
Expected 'a totally different string' to be 'a string' or 'another string'
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I don't think it is a good idea.  Why would you put an or clause in your test?

Comment: Regardless of my disapproval of or and and, by code inspection I think what you want is `or(expect(myString).toEqual('a string'), expect(myString).toEqual('another String'))`.  -- just my guess, not tested

Comment: @emory I have tried this with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples are provided here: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions. However, you're confusing the use of expected conditions, which is used for `browser.wait` and not expects.

Comment: Yeah, this got me confused too. At first, I thought about or and and in expected conditions, but the code examples in the question led me to jasmine matchers.

Answer (score 1):

You can always write a *custom matcher*. In this case, there is no need to write one, the one provided at [Expect item in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747161/expect-item-in-array) would fit your use case. For jasmine 1.x:

```
this.addMatchers({
    toBeIn: function(expected) {
        var posibilities = Array.isArray(expected) ? expected : [expected];
        return posibilities.indexOf(this.actual) > -1;
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
expect(myString).toBeIn(["a string", "another string"]);
```

---

Just FYI, there is also a useful library of custom jasmine matchers: [jasmine-matchers](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers).

Comment: Obviously there are workarounds. My question is how to use the feature that is described in the documentation.

Comment: @KyleRogers probably misunderstood the question. Are you asking about writing expected conditions joined with `or` to pass it to `browser.wait()`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but it just helped me. I am posting it in case it would be useful to someone, not because I think it is the most elegant approach (and it may also be a "workaround"). It works if your strings are really different, and it works for strings, not more generally. For my case, I had to resolve the promise first.

```
myString.getText().then(function(text){
                  expect('a stringanother string'.search(text)).toBeGreaterThan(-1);
                });
```

Of course the above would be quite happy to pass partial matches like 'n' or 'another' or nonsense like 'ngano'. None of those were going to happen in my case.