# Protractor Expect Value to Be X or Y

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I realize similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312697/using-or-in-protractor-expected-conditions?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434826/anyway-to-use-or-in-expects-for-protractor?lq=1) -- but they weren't very clear and I just wanted to see if anything has changed since these were asked over a year ago.

**Scenario**: I have 3 values displayed to the user: `A` and `B` are returned from the API, and `X` is supposed to be the result of subtracting `A - B`.  The values of `A` and `B` are floats on the backend, but are parsed to an Integer on the frontend so the user never sees the decimal values, thus Protractor doesn't know their real value (whether they were rounded up or down).  So, my value of `X` will frequently be +/- 1 from the expected value.

**Use Case:** `expect(someVar).toEqual(x || y);`

**Question**: Has Jasmine implemented anything like an OR statement to execute in one expect? Otherwise I need to create a custom matcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the [`toBeWithinRange`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers/blob/master/test/toBeWithinRange.spec.js) jasmine matcher, coming from the [`jasmine-matchers`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers) help:

```
expect(someVar).toBeWithinRange(expectedValue - 1, expectedValue + 1);
```

There is also a related thread with several more options:

- [Expect item in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747161/expect-item-in-array)

Comment: Perfect, don't know how I didn't find this.  I'll accept your answer in a few minutes.  You answered too fast :D